# Error while generating result. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

When I'm executing my Jmeter script i'm getting below mentioned error

"2021-05-22 02:27:12,862 WARN o.a.j.e.BoundaryExtractor: Boundary Extractor - cr_sessionstate: Error while generating result. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive"

What would be the reason for this error and what is the solution to fix this.

Comment: How did you define the boundary?

Comment: @user7294900 I have defined the boundary using boundary value extractor in Jmeter

Comment: Show the values